# Why is the Postgres C library called libpq instead of libpg?

Tags: postgresql, naming, c-libraries

Everything in the Postgres world has common abbreviation `pg`, and it seems more logical to call Postgres' [c-library](http://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.1/static/libpq.html) `libpg`, rather than `libpq`. Why is it called `libpq`? Is `libpg` already taken by another tool?

Answer (score 13, accepted):

From https://pgolub.wordpress.com/2010/09/21/libpq-stands-for/, credited to Bruce Momjian:

> Libpq is called ‘libpq’ because of the original use of the QUEL query language, i.e. lib Post-QUEL. We have a proud backward-compatibility history with this library.